# preencher campo datatime

Tags: php, html5, codeigniter

estou tentando preencher o `input` `datetime-local` mas o campo fica em branco, já tentei mandar no formato **americano** e **brasileiro** porém não vem de jeito nenhum.
no banco de dados fica armazenado no formato americano: **2017-02-20 19:19:00**
e no html eu tento inserir assim:

```
<?php $date = new DateTime($situacao[0]['data_inicio']) ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtDataInicio" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Data Inicio</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="txtDataInicio" name="txtDataInicio" placeholder="Nome da Função" value="<?php echo (empty($situacao[0]['data_inicio']))? set_value('txtDataInicio'): $date->format('y-M-dh:m') ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

nessa linha eu já tentei formatar em alguns formatos, mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Amigo, daria para colocar o código completo ? Ficaria mais fácil pra gente ajudar você

Comment: o código completo da exibição? vou colocar lá

Answer (score 1):

Caso seja só pra exibir do banco de dados no input, você pode exibir diretamente, sem o uso do `DateTime`

```
<?php $date = (!empty($situacao[0]['data_inicio'])) ? date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($situacao[0]['data_inicio'])) : set_value('txtDataInicio'); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtDataInicio" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Data Inicio</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="txtDataInicio" name="txtDataInicio" placeholder="Nome da Função" value="<?php echo $date;?>">
    </div>
</div>
```

Nesse código ele formata para o padrão brasileiro **dd/mm/YYYY H:i:s** mas você pode utilizar qualquer padrão tendo em conta que sejá válido na função `date()`

Comment: não é apenas para ser exibido, ele será editado pelo usuário e devolvido para o banco de dados, por isso mantive o 'type="datetime-local"'

Comment: Em qual formato ele deve estar no input para o usuário editar ?

Comment: no formato brasileiro como mostrou acima

Comment: Apenas altere então o `type` para **datetime-local** e utilize o código que passei para você, pois ele pega a data no formato EUA do banco de dados e no input ele traz formatado em PT-BR para você

Comment: então, no meu código que deixei na pergunta, eu já tentei desse modo porém sem sucesso, o input fica em branco

Comment: @DaniloD verifica antes se está realmente a retornar alguma data, fazendo um `print` ou `echo`, porque segundo o código acima, deveria funcionar normalmente.

Comment: É @DaniloD, faz como o @Edilson falou. Antes do código `$date` da um `print_r($situacao[0]['data_inicio'])` para ver o que está retornando.